# XKB - configurations not working properly

Tags: fedora, x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xkb

I added the following to **/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us**:

```
key <AC06> {        [         h, H, Left            ]       };
key <AC07> {        [         j, J, Down            ]       };
key <AC08> {        [         k, K, Up              ]       };
key <AC09> {        [         l, L, Right           ]       };
key <AD08> { [ i, I, Home, Home          ] };
key <AB08> { [ comma, less, End, End         ] };
key <CAPS> { [ ISO_Level3_Shift ] };
```

Because arrow keys and Home/End keys are just too goddamn away. The problem is, these modifications get ignored in some programs.

They work well in browers and some text editors like vscode and emacs gui, while they do not in Sublime Text and Konsole (KDE Terminal) for example.

Is there a fix. I'm using Fedora if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just hacked together the following solution. It not only works in Sublime Text, but also allows to select text with <kbd>shift</kbd>.

1. Add `preserve[Shift+LevelThree] = Shift;` to `…/xdb/types/iso9995`. Details on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1048906/682414).
2. Add `type="THREE_LEVEL"` and `actions[Group1]= [NoAction(), NoAction(), RedirectKey(keycode=<UP>, clearmods=Lock)` (for up) to your entries in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`.

My entries with slightly different keys looks like this:

```
key <AD07> { type="THREE_LEVEL",
   symbols[Group1]= [ u,            U,         Home,        Home ],
   actions[Group1]= [      NoAction(),      NoAction(),   RedirectKey(keycode=<HOME>, clearmods=Lock) ]
};
key <AD08> { type="THREE_LEVEL",
   symbols[Group1]= [ i,            I,         Up,        Up ],
   actions[Group1]= [      NoAction(),      NoAction(),   RedirectKey(keycode=<UP>, clearmods=Lock) ]
};
key <AD09> { type="THREE_LEVEL",
   symbols[Group1]= [ o,            O,         End,        End ],
   actions[Group1]= [      NoAction(),      NoAction(),   RedirectKey(keycode=<END>, clearmods=Lock) ]
};
key <AC07> { type="THREE_LEVEL",
   symbols[Group1]= [ j,            J,         Left,      Left ],
   actions[Group1]= [      NoAction(),      NoAction(),   RedirectKey(keycode=<LEFT>, clearmods=Lock) ]
};
key <AC08> { type="THREE_LEVEL",
   symbols[Group1]= [ k,            l,         Down,      Down ],
   actions[Group1]= [      NoAction(),      NoAction(),   RedirectKey(keycode=<DOWN>, clearmods=Lock) ]
};
key <AC09> { type="THREE_LEVEL",
   symbols[Group1]= [ l,            L,         Right,      Right ],
   actions[Group1]= [      NoAction(),      NoAction(),   RedirectKey(keycode=<RGHT>, clearmods=Lock) ]
};
```

Read [this article on the Archlinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_keyboard_extension#Caps_hjkl_as_vimlike_arrow_keys) for more details.

Maybe you can skip 1. and the type declaration if you don't want to select text with <kbd>shift</kbd>.

Comment: Does this still work for you? Everything in Gnome works fine, except of the Sublime

Comment: @Fuxi, if it doesn't work in certain apps, they might use the keycode instead of the defined actions. I think, I had this problem once in Atom, but I could change it in the settings.

Right now I use https://github.com/sezanzeb/key-mapper